# How to require class that is in the same directory in Ruby 1.9.x

Tags: ruby, class

I have two ruby files say A and B in certain folder.

The class A code is as follows:

```
class A
  def self.foo
    puts "foo"
  end
end

A.foo
```

The class B code is as follows:

```
class B
  def self.bar
    puts "bar"   
  end
end

B.bar
A.foo
```

When i try to run class B file, am getting the following error:

```
bar
b.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant A (NameError)
```

I don't want to use modules. So, how do I reference A.foo from class B?

Comment: Why you are not trying to require 'a.rb' into b's file .

Comment: i tired that but getting this error - require': cannot load such file -- a (LoadError)

Comment: how are you requiring the file a into b .

Comment: @amala if you do 'require' in any of those files, then update the code, exactly as you have it.

Comment: @amala and please, update you question title to something more descriptive, "uninitialized constant A (NameError)" is *very* generic. Better would be "How to properly require class file in Ruby 1.9.." or "How to make class visible in another class.." or ect. depending on your intentions.

Comment: @Ernest - Now i changed the question title.

Comment: @amala thank you, looks much better ;)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this answers your question, because I dont fully understand what your intention is.

Your `b.rb` script is not aware of the class A from `a.rb`, you know, hence the error. There are several ways to tell `b.rb` to use `a.rb`.

1. you can add to the file `b.rb`

   ```
   require 'a'
   ```
2. you can run the b.rb script like this:

   ```
   ruby -r a.rb b.rb
   ```

A side note. In both cases the code in `a.rb`

```
    A.foo
```

is executed as well. You can make that code runnable only when `a.rb` is directly run, by enclosing the code to run in:

```
    if __FILE__ == $0
      # code to run when a.rb is executed directly
      A.foo
    end
```

Comment: `require 'a'` will not load file, unless you place `a.rb` into one of the `$LOAD_PATH` folders, `require './a'` will do.

Comment: @NashBridges ..or use require_relative in 1.9

Comment: Right, in ruby 1.9 the `require` statement does not look in the current directory. ruby 1.8.7 still does it.